# Comprehensive list of differencies between versions of DirectX, shaders: features, incompatibilities, requirements etc

Tags: comparison, directx, shader, hlsl

Is there a comprehensive comparison of different versions of DirectX, different versions of shaders?

There's an article on Wikipedia about [HLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLSL) with comparison of different versions of shaders. It is useful, but only if you already know a lot of details about shaders (what is instruction predication? what are gradient instructions?). Another problem is that given one source code, different versions of pixel shaders produce different results. It would be much more useful if the article gave some basic idea what is being compared and what are its usages. It would give information about what you really need, what are requirements for your application, what you need to learn.

There're a lot of articles on the Internet about specific features of DirectX (like "Hardware tesselation is supported now, yay!"), but I couldn't find full lists of changes. There're [lists of breaking changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205073(VS.85).aspx) between different versions of DirectX on MSDN, but they provide information only on breaking changes, not new features, and are focused on API. There're lists like [API features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172268(VS.85).aspx), but they are neither detailed nor comprehensive.

What I want is a comprehensive detailed list of differences between versions of DirectX, versions of shaders, preferably with short exlanations of features for those who only start learning DirectX, HLSL etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New features for DX10: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172268(v=VS.85).aspx
New features for DX11: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476342(v=VS.85).aspx

They ALWAYS write a document telling you what is introduced in each new DX version ...

The real skill comes from reading the new list of features and then researching them in the help system.  Its waaaaaay too detailed a thing to put in one document.  So they point you int he right direction and leave you to work out the rest by reading the REST of the documentation.  Sure maybe they could make life easier by putting it all linked from one document but if you actually read the "Programming Guide" its ALL there in more detail than you could ever hope for ...